# Were any books (prior to 1240 CE) teaching תֶּרַח Terach was reincarnated into אִיוֹב Iyov (as described by Zohar, Zera Barekh & Simchat HaRegel)?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, avot-patriarch-fathers, job-iyov-book-of, reincarnation

**Were any books** (prior to 1240 CE) **teaching תֶּרַח Terach**  **was reincarnated into אִיוֹב Iyov** (as described by Zohar, Zera Barekh & Simchat HaRegel)?

https://www.sefaria.org/Simchat_HaRegel_on_Pesach_Haggadah%2C_Magid%2C_In_the_Beginning_Our_Fathers_Were_Idol_Worshipers.1.5?lang=bi

Comment: There were no widely accepted books that explicitly affirmed gilgul at all. Gilgul was considered part of the secrets of Torah not to be openly discussed.